# How to enable / disable action in Netbeans Platform

Tags: java, netbeans, action, netbeans-platform

I have spent almost three days trying to do a simple enable / disable of Actions in the netbeans plaform, something that I though was going to be simple, and should be a common feature is more complex than I thought.

At the begging I tried to see if there was an setEnable() method on the default actions generated and to my surprise there is not. Then I started looking into that and I found that most common method to do it was setting a conditionally enabled action (which depends on a Cookie class), So I figured out how to add a fake class to the Lookup so it gets enabled and disabled, I did it the following way. To test it out I added the following code to another action which should enable or disable the second one.

```
private final PlottingStarted plottingStarted = new PlottingStarted(); 


@Override 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    // TODO implement action body 
    if (Lookup.getDefault().lookup(PlottingStarted.class) == null) { 
        ic.add(plottingStarted); 
    }else{ 
        ic.remove(plottingStarted); 
    }
```

So PlottingStarted is a fake object I created which only purpose is being in the lookup to disable or enable the action.

For some reason it did not do anything at all an the Action was always disabled. I tried many things and finally I gave up.

Then I tried a different approach and was using AbstractActions which do have the setEnabled() ability.

To retrieve the action I based myself on one the Geertjan blogs and I created the following method

```
public Action findAction(String actionName) { 
    FileObject myActionsFolder = FileUtil.getConfigFile("Actions/RealTimeViewer"); 
    if (myActionsFolder != null){ 
        FileObject[] myActionsFolderKids = myActionsFolder.getChildren(); 
        for (FileObject fileObject : myActionsFolderKids) { 
            //Probably want to make this more robust, 
            //but the point is that here we find a particular Action: 
            if (fileObject.getName().contains(actionName)) { 
                try { 
                    DataObject dob = DataObject.find(fileObject); 
                    InstanceCookie ic = dob.getLookup().lookup(InstanceCookie.class); 
                    if (ic != null) { 
                        Object instance = ic.instanceCreate(); 
                        if (instance instanceof Action) { 
                            Action a = (Action) instance; 
                            return a; 
                        } 
                    } 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                    ErrorManager.getDefault().notify(ErrorManager.WARNING, e); 
                    return null; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

This method worked perfectly and I was able to retrieve the action and call its setEnabled() method. Unfortunately no matter why I did the Action was always enabled.

Reading some literature I found that I should add the following to the registration of the action "lazy = false" and finally I was able to enable and disable the Action... But off course the default registration is lost and I have no Icons and Names.

Now I decided to post again because I cannot believe that it need to be that complex, there must be a way to do it easier. The only thing I need is to have a PLAY / STOP functionality, when PLAY is enabled STOP is disabled and vice-versa.

Comment: I assume play/stop are bound to some kind of input elements?

Comment: It's unclear how the actions are triggered. Anyway, at PLAY, you should add the actionlistener, and at STOP, you should remove the actionlistener. I have no idea why you're trying to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this myself but it seems to be covered in Chapter 5.1.2.1 "Complex Enablement" of the book "Netbeans Platform for Beginners". https://leanpub.com/nbp4beginners

The book is not free but the corresponding code sample is available on 
github. https://github.com/walternyland/nbp4beginners/tree/master/chapters/ch05/5.1.2.1 He extends AbstractAction overrides the resultChanged method and uses super.setEnabled().

```
@ActionID(id = "org.carsales.evaluator.EvaluateCarAction1", category = "Car")
@ActionRegistration(displayName = "not-used", lazy = false)
public class EvaluateCarAction extends AbstractAction
implements ContextAwareAction, LookupListener {
// ...

@Override
public void resultChanged(LookupEvent le) {
    //Optionally, check if the property is set to the value you're interested in
   //prior to enabling the Action.
   super.setEnabled(result.allInstances().size() > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody for your responses. I finally got it to work by extending AbstractAction, it seems that even if you register "lazy = false" some of the registration is still being done by the platform and you just need some minor tweaking in the Action constructor. The final result was

```
@ActionID(
        category = "RealTimeViewer",
        id = "main.java.com.graph.actions.StopPlotting"
)
@ActionRegistration(
        //iconBase = "main/java/com/graph/images/stop-plotting-24x24.png",
        displayName = "#CTL_StopPlotting",
        lazy = false
)
@ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/RealTimeViewer", position = 600)
@Messages("CTL_StopPlotting=Stop Plotting")
public final class StopPlotting extends AbstractAction{

private static final String ICON = "main/java/com/dacsys/cna/core/graph/images/stop-plotting-24x24.png";

public StopPlotting() {
    putValue(SMALL_ICON, ImageUtilities.loadImageIcon(ICON, false));
    putValue(NAME, Bundle.CTL_StopPlotting());
    this.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO implement action body
    Action a = new ActionsHelper().findAction("StartPlotting");
    if (a != null){
        if (a != null){
            if (a.isEnabled()){
                a.setEnabled(false);
                this.setEnabled(true);
            }else{
                a.setEnabled(true);
                this.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

}